# Does data needs to have a specific format to upload it in Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, boot2docker

I would like to know if there is a specific way to upload data to Docker, I've been stuck on this during a week and I am sure the answer will be something simple.
Does anyone know? I am working with a windows 10 machine.

Comment: By upload what are you referring? Uploading docker images to registry or mounting a docker volume to host machine?

Comment: For example, I want to upload a txt file containing a network of my interest so I can replace a network inside another container (which os owned by another person but I can have access). Like in this page https://github.com/jdrudolph/photon/issues/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `docker cp` command to copy the file.

For eg: If you want to copy `abc.txt` to location `/usr/local/folder` inside some docker container(you can get docker container name from `NAMES` column by executing command `docker ps`.) then you just execute,

```
docker cp abc.txt ContainerName:/usr/local/folder
```

(abc.txt is a local to the foler from where you are executing the command. You can provide the full path of the file.)

After this just get into the container by,

```
docker exec -it ContainerName bash
```

then `cd /usr/local/folder`. you will see your file copied their.

Comment: I get this error:
"GetFileAttributesEx C:\Users\Sysmaster\reactome.txt: The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: paste the complete command which you are using. Which OS you have in your host machine? Windows or linux?

Comment: $ docker cp reactome.txt zen_goodall:/photon/db/reactome.txt

I'm using windows 10 and using the Docker Quickstart terminal

Comment: what is the full path of reactome.txt ?

Comment: C:\Users\Sysmaster\Documents\Kitematic\zen_goodall\data

zen_goodall is the name of the container and photon is the tool container.

Comment: goto to path C:\Users\Sysmaster\Documents\Kitematic\zen_goodall\data (cd C:\Users\Sysmaster\Documents\Kitematic\zen_goodall\data )and then execute docker cp reactome.txt zen_goodall:/photon/db/reactome.txt

Comment: or use this command   docker cp C:/Users/Sysmaster/Documents/Kitematic/zen_goodall/data/reactome.txt zen_goodall:/photon/db/reactome.txt

Comment: Now this message appears:

> Error response from daemon: lstat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/4bb3f48b6cf1ebe2e508d335e5c1936a9ba94b52797850eb05aa601f669daca0/photon/db: no such file or directory.


I guess it must be an error of the other container, right?

Comment: Can you execute(docker exec -it zen_goodall bash) to get in into container and check of /photon/db/ directory exits or not. Command cd /photon/db/ .....it think you don't have this directory inside container that's what the error tells. You can create these directories

Comment: execute these command in sequence......1. docker exec -it zen_goodall bash
2. mkdir /photon
3. mkdir /photon/db                                then execute "docker cp C:/Users/Sysmaster/Documents/Kitematic/zen_goodall/data/reac‌​tome.txt zen_goodall:/photon/db/reactome.txt"

Comment: It works! :-D thank you sooo much for help me out! You're a genius!

Answer (score 1):

You can mount directories on the host system inside the container and access their contents that way, if that's what you mean by 'data'.

You should check out [Manage data in containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) for more info.

Comment: I meant, files. I don't know if the files should contain a specific format. For example, a normal txt file.